# Socks5 multiple requests

Tags: php, proxy, connection, socks

i'm using a socks5 php library that connects to a proxy and sends data through it. The library works when i do a single request to a http server, but when i do the second in receive empty string and at the third i receive an error

> 10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your
>   host machine.

I don't understand why that happens, i looked trought RFC and wikipedia about the socks5 server and i think all the connection is correct. But still don't get second response.

The library code is one file and i get it from here [Socks5Socket](https://github.com/maxia/php-socks5socket/blob/master/Socks5Socket.class.php)

And my code is the next one

```
set_time_limit(100);
error_reporting ( E_ALL );

require_once "Socks5Socket.php";

$s = new \Socks5Socket\Client();
$s->configureProxy(array(
    'hostname' => '162.144.56.44',
    'port' => 60088
));
$s->connect('en.wikipedia.org', 80);
$request = "GET /wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection HTTP/1.1\r\n".
           "Host: en.wikipedia.org\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";
$s->send($request);
$response = $s->readAll();

//At this point all OK



$request2 = "GET /wiki/No-till_farming HTTP/1.1\r\n".
           "Host: en.wikipedia.org\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";

$s->send($request2);
// Empty string here, no error
$response2 = $s->readAll();


$s->send($request2);
// Errno 10053
$response3 = $s->readAll();
file_put_contents("response.txt",$response2);
$response = substr($response,strpos($response,"»")+1);
//echo $response;
echo "<br><br>".substr($response,strpos($response,"\r\n\r\n")+1);
```

Comment: Did you verify that the target HTTP server is honoring the keep-alive?  What is the value of the `Connection` header in the first response? If the server is closing the connection after sending the first response, the proxy is going to close the connection to your client, so you will have to re-connect to the proxy again before sending the second request.

Comment: BTW, using `readAll()` is not the correct way to read an HTTP response. You need to actually read the HTTP headers and parse them to know how to read the rest of the response data. That means using `readLine()` and `read()` appropriately, instead of using `readAll()`. You have to follow the rules for HTTP processing in order to ensure the integrity of the connection, especially if you want to use HTTP keep-alives.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You were right, the http server was closing my connection. I've tried with a smtp server and all ok.

Comment: HTTP does not guarantee persistent connections. You have to be prepared to reconnect on every request, at worst. HTTP 1.1 made persistency a default, but not a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that the http server was closing my connection before i could do anything else. I've tried with a SMTP server and the connection was no more closed.